# UI Router resolve throws Unexpected Get request in Angular

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angular-ui-router

I'm using UI router and define a site-wide resolve.

```
$stateProvider
  .state('site', {
    abstract: true,
    resolve: {
      exampleResolve: function(MyApiService) {
        return MyApiService.get();
      }
    },
    views: {
      'site': {
        template: '<ui-view/>'
      }
    }
  })
```

However, I have a custom directive, and when I unit test it, I'm getting 'Error: Unexpected request: GET /api/example' (which is the `MyApiService.get()).

```
it('should do something', function() {
  scope.example.data = '123';
  scope.$digest();
  element.triggerHandler('blur');
  console.log(element);
})
```

Somehow throws `Error: Unexpected request: GET /api/example`

Answer (score 1):

Try mocking **MyApiService** so that call should not delegate to actual implementation.

```
it( 'should do something', inject( function( MyApiService ) {
spyOn( MyApiService, 'get' ).and.callFake( function() {
    return true;
} );
scope.example.data = '123';
scope.$digest();
element.triggerHandler( 'blur' );
console.log( element );} ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to instantiate service in your test case as follows.

```
//you need to inject dependencies first
beforeEach(inject(function(MyApiService) {
    MyApiService.get();        
}));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
try to mention <ui-view/> in HTML
//HTML
<body>
<div ui-view="site"></div>
</body>

//Javascript
$stateProvider
.state('sites',{
views: {
  'site': {
    templateUrl: 'sites-site.html',
    controller: function($scope){ ... controller stuff just for site view ..}     

  }
}
})
```